# PHP how can I count the amount of each letter in a string with letters?

Tags: php, css, string, loops, output

How can I count the amount of each letter in a string with letters?

For example:

```
$string = "ababdcbadbcabcbcadcbadbc"
```

Now I have to count how many a's, b's, c's and d's are in the string and I have to print the result in a diagram.

Tnx and keep programming! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
$string = "ababdcbadbcabcbcadcbadbc";
print_r(array_count_values(str_split($string)));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 6
    [b] => 8
    [d] => 4
    [c] => 6
)
```

---

> I have to print the result in a diagram

And here comes the lovely diagram!

```
array_multisort($arr);

foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    echo str_repeat($k,$v)."<br>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
dddd
aaaaaa
cccccc
bbbbbbbb
```

See the full [**working demo**](https://eval.in/137431)

Comment: I need to print the result in a bar chart.. I don't know if this is possible. Tnx for the help anyway!

Comment: Why not ? Nothing is impossible :) It will be better if you give a try with this link and comeback if you have a problem . http://code.web-max.ca/image_graph.php

Answer (score 2):

Look at this
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php

Hope that helps. Let me know, if not.

> ```
> <?php
>  $data = "Two Ts and one F.";
>
>  foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
>     echo "There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string.\n";
>  }
>  ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be it will help you.

```
print_r(array_count_values(str_split("string")));
```

Goodluck,
Cheers.